# Harmonic Function on Disk with Discontinuity on Boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an old qualifying exam problem that I can't solve:

Given bounded harmonic function $h(z)$ on $\mathbb{D}$ with limits s.t.  $\lim_{r \to 1^-} h(re^{it})$ equals 1 for $0<t<\pi$ and equals 0 for $\pi<t< 2\pi$. Find $h(\frac{1}{2})$.

This seems mysterious and I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that $h(1/2) = 1/2$.

This follows from symmetry.  Specifically, the function $h(z)$ is uniquely determined in the interior and, because of the symmetry of the boundary conditions, must satisfy the functional equation
$$
h(\overline{z}) = 1 - h(z).
$$
(To prove this equation, observe that $h(z) + h(\overline{z})$ is harmonic and is equal to $1$ almost everywhere on the boundary.)  It follows that $h(z) = 1/2$ for values of $z$ in the interior of the disk that lie on the real axis.

Comment: But then h is constant, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez What do you mean?

Comment: Ah! I thought the function was holomorphic, not harmonic.

Comment: Incidentally, if you don't notice the symmetry argument, it's also possible to solve for the function $h$ directly using either Fourier series or (equivalently) the Poisson integral formula.

Comment: Dude that is so awesome! Thanks Jim the man!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{\rm h}\pars{r,\theta} = \half + \fermi\pars{r,\theta}}$ where $\ds{\fermi\pars{1^{-},\theta} = \half}$ when $\ds{0 < \theta < \pi}$ and $\ds{-\,\half}$ when $\ds{\pi < \theta < 2\pi}$. Then, $\ds{\fermi\pars{r,\theta} = -\fermi\pars{r,2\pi - \theta}}$.
$\ds{\fermi\pars{r,\theta} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_{n}r^{n}\sin\pars{n\theta}}$:
\begin{align}
\half = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_{n}\sin\pars{n\theta}\quad\imp\quad&
\half\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\pars{m\theta}\,\dd\theta
=
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_{n}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\pars{m\theta}\sin\pars{n\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=
A_{m}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2}\pars{m\theta}\,\dd\theta = A_{m}\,{\pi \over 2}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> A_{n} &= {1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\pars{n\theta}\,\dd\theta
> = {1 \over \pi}{-\cos\pars{n\pi} + 1 \over n}
> = {1 \over \pi}{-\pars{-1}^{n} + 1 \over n}
> =
> \left\lbrace%
> \begin{array}{lcl}
> {2 \over n\pi} & \mbox{if} & n\ \mbox{is odd}
> \\[2mm]
> 0 & \mbox{if} & n\ \mbox{is even}
> \end{array}\right.
> \end{align}

$$
\fermi\pars{r,\theta}
=
{2 \over \pi}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{r^{2n + 1}\sin\pars{\bracks{2n + 1}\theta}
\over 2n + 1}
=
{2 \over \pi}\Im
\overbrace{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{z^{2n + 1} \over 2n + 1}}^{\ds{\equiv\ \varphi\pars{z}}}\,,
\qquad z \equiv r\expo{\ic\theta} \equiv x + y\ic\,,\quad x, y\ \in\ {\mathbb R}
$$

> $\ds{\varphi'\pars{z} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{2n} = {1 \over 1 - z^{2}}
> = {1 \over 2\pars{1 - z}} + {1 \over 2\pars{1 + z}}\,,\quad\varphi\pars{0} = 0}$
> \begin{align}
> &\Im\varphi\pars{z} = \half\Im\ln\pars{1 + z \over 1 - z}
> = \half\Im\ln\pars{\pars{1 + z}\pars{1 - z^{*}} \over \verts{1 - z}^{2}}
> =\half\Im\ln\pars{1 + z - z^{*} - \verts{z}^{2}}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\Im\ln\pars{1 - r^{2} + 2y\ic}
> =\half\,\arctan\pars{2y \over 1 - r^{2}}=
> \half\,\arctan\pars{{2r \over 1 - r^{2}}\,\sin\pars{\theta}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
{\rm h}\pars{r,\theta}
=
\half  + {1 \over \pi}\,\arctan\pars{{2r \over 1 - r^{2}}\,\sin\pars{\theta}}}
$$